# Add text after first element

Tags: jquery

I tried to add text after the first children, without success

```
<a href="#" name="usernameMenu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>add text here
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

I tried some command.

My last one

```
$('a[name="usernameMenu"] span:eq(0)').after().append("add text here");
```

I get

```
<a href="#" name="usernameMenu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">add text here</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `.append`

Try like this

```
$('a[name="usernameMenu"] span:eq(0)').after("add text here");
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/03j0hwqn/)**</kbd>

Comment: that work. if want to remove the same text, what command need to be used?

Comment: You wanna to remove `add text here` ?  @roberttrudel